# Which software can check whether two algebras are isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algorithms, math-software

Given two algebras $A$, $B$ in terms of generators and relations, is there some software/algorithm which can check whether $A \cong B$? It looks like this is [not true in general](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2608958/167197), so is there software that can check this in special cases?

Answer (score 8):

No, this problem is undecidable. If it were decidable then you could determine whether a finitely presented group $G$ is trivial, by checking whether its group algebra $k[G]$ is isomorphic to $k$ (over $k$); this is known to be undecidable.

The corresponding question for commutative algebras is not known to be decidable or undecidable, at least as of [2012](http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/sampler.pdf).

Comment: However one should keep in mind, that similar problems, like the word problem (of groups), while undecideable in general, still have algorithms that work in many cases. So the questions remains, if there is software, that is able so solve the problem at least in many instances...

Comment: I'm presuming you know of a result that if k[G] is isomorphic to k (over k) then G is trivial. $\hspace{1.03 in}$ Do you have a proof or reference for such a result? ​ ​

Comment: @Ricky: the dimension of $k[G]$ over $k$ is the cardinality of $G$, which is equal to $1$ iff $G$ is trivial.